# Styling seaside confirm dialog

Tags: seaside

Seaside has a convenient message `WAComponent>>confirm:` that creates a dialog with yes/no buttons, however there is no CSS styling on this component. Is it possible to add styling to this component or do I need to subclass `WAYesOrNoDialog` in my app to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to apply your styles to the `WAYesOrNoDialog`:

1. If your calling it from your top level component, then subclassing it is the way, but you'd still need to implement `confirm:onAnswer:` on your own component to reference you're own class.
2. If you call it from within another component (that is not top level), you can render the component that's going to perform the `confirm:onAnswer:` within a `<div>` in the parent component.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I’m going the subclass route and override the message